# GeoServer - Java Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException occurs when trying to create a layer using a CSV Datastore

Tags: csv, layer, geoserver

Using the GeoServer GUI, I created a CSV datastore selecting the CSV file (on local host) via the Browse button on the "New Vector Data Source" screen. The datastore was created successfully. However, when I try to create a new layer (hit Publish button) using this newly created datastore, The screen (below) is displayed (shown in 2 parts). It shows that there is a Java Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException. The file is definitely there - I selected from the Browse button on the GeoServer GUI.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks very much.

More info:
GeoServer version: 2.18.2

Example piece of CSV file:

StationId,StationName,State,Lat,Lon,Node,Filename
8729210,Panama City Beach,FL,30.211,-85.88,6935,8729210_WL.png
8638901,CBBT Chesapeake Channel,VA,37.033333,-76.083333,28312,8638901_WL.png
.
.

[image: Java error screenshot- part1]

[image: Java error screenshot- part2]

Comment: does the user running GeoServer have permission to read the file?

Comment: It is better to paste in the relevant text from the GeoServer log file than to use pictures of the error as they are unreadable on many devices and can't be found using search tool

Comment: Yes permissions are wide open" Found this https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8905. It is hard to believe that this has been open as an issue for 3 years though. That would mean that this feature never worked?

Comment: Looks like you're the 2nd person to try it - it will be fixed in tonight's nightly builds. But I would strongly advice against using a CSV file for a datastore for any production use - it is **very** slow.

Comment: I apologize Ian - I didn't realize that it was not a very used feature. Thank you so much for updating. Do you know when that would be available in a release? Thank you again.

Comment: I applied the patch to 2.20.x, 2.19.x and 2.18.x so it looks like it will be in 2.18.3 on the 18th April - https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Release-Schedule

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just so this doesn't go unanswered.

You have run into a known bug ([GEOS-8905](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8905)) which will be fixed in the [next releases](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Release-Schedule) of GeoServer.

**I strongly recommend not using CSV files in a production setting as they will be very slow and have no indexing available so the entire file will be read every map draw.**